# Django ORM - assigning a raw value to DecimalField

Tags: python, django, django-models, casting, django-orm

EDIT!!! - The casting of the value to a string seems to work fine when I create a *new* object, but when I try to edit an existing object, it does not allow it.

So I have a decimal field in one of my models of Decimal(3,2)

When I query up all these objects and try to set this field:

```
fieldName = 0.85
```

OR

```
fieldName = .85
```

It will throw a hissy fit, "Cannot convert float to DecimalField, try converting to a string first"...

So then I do:

```
fieldName = str(0.85)
```

same error.

I even tried:

```
fieldName = "0.85"
```

Same error. Am I running into some sort of framework bug here, or what? Note that when I actually go into Django Admin and manually edit the objects, it works fine.

I am running Django 1.1 on Python 2.6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from decimal import Decimal
object.fieldName = Decimal("0.85")
```

or

```
f = 0.85
object.fieldName = Decimal(str(f))
```

Answer (score 3):

The Django [DecimalField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) is "...represented in by a python [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) instance."  You might try:

```
>>> obj.fieldName = Decimal("0.85")
```

Behavior may also vary depending on the database backend you are using.  With sqlite, I am able to assign string values to DecimalFields in new and existing objects without error.

Comment: Just saw this. Seems that form inputs put into a model instance with the sqlite backend will stay as unicode strings which stops you from doing any maths on them.